# (Sonarlint 2.0.0) Error line is not highlighted, issues view is empty,

Tags: eclipse, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

I've just install the latest SonarLint : [org.sonarlint.eclipse.site-2.0.0.20160404-1547-RELEASE.zip](https://bintray.com/artifact/download/sonarsource/SonarLint-for-Eclipse/releases/org.sonarlint.eclipse.site-2.0.0.20160404-1547-RELEASE.zip)

My SonarQube server version is **5.4**.
I could bind my Java project to the server successfully, and the projet has the SonarLint icon.

But When I code some wrong things in the Java projet, **the error lines are not highlighted, the Issue view remain empty**.
But the **Maven sonar build raise many errors in the SonarQube server**.

And in the **SonarLint console** (I've activated debug) I see some output everytime I save the file, It seems that the analyse is well triggered.

But in the Java file editor the Soanarlint error is not displayed, juste the Eclipse ones.

Is there anything to activate to get them ?

Thanks for your help?

WOGNIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is on the google forum of SonarLint :

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarlint/kExoU5cJ2FU